# Migrate a .mdb app to Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, migration

I have a database in access and it haves "embeeded" code making the database works as a visual basic program via macros and vb programming.
But its not a Visual Basic application its like just code, forms, macros added to the access database.

The file format is .mdb or .mde

My question is:

Its possible to split the "application" and tables? Migrate that database to a SQL Server database and attach the "application" to the new database?

Comment: Consider migrating to a .ADP file (even though for some reason they may not be supported in future). This is an Access front end and native SQL Server back end (no linked tables), but you need to record all your VBA and macros for ADO, not Jet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to migrate a .mdb file into SQL Server.

1) Just create a new database on SQL Server.

2) Right click the name of the database.

3) Click on tasks.

4) Click on Import Data...

5) Then browse to your .mdb file. There are instructions as you go along.

Comment: But that will migrate tables and data from access database to sql server.

What about all the code, macros, etc?

Comment: Last time I read, SQL Server does not support Macros. You will have to use stored procedures if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to do exactly what the "SQL Server Migration Assistant" utility does. For more information, see

[SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access (AccessToSQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh313039%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Its not a matter of migrating tables or data.

Comment: My .mdb or .mde file contains a large application wich
Im working on migrating to .NET ASP. 
I was workin on it for 3 months and I still have 50% of the application done
So imagine the code behind that access db.
I know how to migrate tables to sql. The problem is the code